# How to find multiple of fixed number using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started using python a few days back and need some help.

Using for loop, I want to get the result:

```
2
8
32
128
```

What I tried is here:

```
x = 2
y = 4

for x in range (y):
    x = 4 * x
    print(x)
```

I expect the output of

```
2
8
32
128
```

but instead I get

```
0
4
8
12
```

Comment: `for x in range (y):` means that `x` will get assigned the following values: 0,1,2,3 (so it has nothing to do with your initialization of `x` - which is _not_ a fixed number)

Comment: Replace `for x in range (y):` by `for i in range (y):`, though the most pythonic solution is something like `print( '\n'.join(str(2**k) for k in range(1,8,2)))`

Comment: Try printing `x` at the *top* of the loop, and see if that helps explain what is going on.

Comment: @Scott. Good advice, but only if it's not the loop variable

Comment: @MadPhysicist: That wasn't meant as a fix (which it isn't), but rather to highlight the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest thing would be to do:

```
>>> y = 4
>>> x = 2
>>> for i in range(y):
...     print(x * y**i)
...
2
8
32
128
```

As others have mentioned you are assigning the value of the range(y) output to x which is causing you issues.

Comment: I believe he's actually trying to do this y times, not y times multiplying x by y

Comment: You're saying the number on the right hand of the multiplication (4) is a constant. And he wants to know how to multiply this constant y times? If so he could change the loop to read: ```for i in range(y): print(x * 4**i)```. It will iterate y times.

Comment: ya that's what I'm saying

Comment: Hi, thank you all for the help.
I want to print the series starting with x = 2 and each element in the series being 4 times the number immediately previous to it. And number of the entries to be equal to y=4.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=2
y=4

for i in range(1,y+1):
    print(x)
    x = x * 4
```

output:

```
2  
8  
32  
128
```

Comment: It is a good practice to use `_` instead of `i` for don't-care variables.